# echo colored text which changes colors dynamically

Tags: shell-script, scripting, echo

Is there any way that I can print a colored text on console which keeps on changing its colors dynamically(with or without a specified time interval) just like some greeting cards in which the greeting changes colors?

I am aware of printing a colored text using

```
echo eg: echo -e "\e[1;34m Hi dude, Welcome to the Matrix \e[0m"
```

but I wish this text keeps changing color.

Is it actually possible?

Comment: it is possible, sort of, with some well-timed use of `printf <TEXT>` and `printf "\r"` so that you'll effectively rewrite the already printed line after a couple of secs or whatever.

Comment: @AlexejMagura if i understand this correct,according to your method, my terminal window will end up doing only the color changes, and it will be useless for other purpose. Is there any way that we can move this color change process to the back end while still be able to work on this instance of terminal normally?

Comment: run it in the background using `&` like so: `cmd &`, or make it part of your prompt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't print text with instructions to change its colour repeatedly. You *can* write different-coloured text over the top of your original text, with something like this:

```
i=0
while true
do
    echo -en "\r\e[1;3${i}mWelcome to the Matrix\e[0m"
    i=$(((i+1)%8))
    sleep 0.25
done
```

That will cycle through all the bright colours, changing four times a second. `\r` is a carriage return, which moves the cursor back to the start of the line; `echo -n` suppresses the newline at the end of the output.

That only works for a single line, and the last line of output. You can also use a different set of escapes to move around a little more. `\e[3A` will move the cursor up three lines, and you can then rewrite the text up there again:

```
i=0
while true
do
    echo -e "\e[0;3$(((i+1)%8))mHello!\e[0m"
    echo -e "\e[1;3${i}mWelcome to the Matrix\e[0m"
    i=$(((i+1)%8))
    sleep 0.25
    echo -e "\e[3A"
done
```

That will write two lines in different colours, both changing constantly.

These are all [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), and there are a lot of them. If you're using them a lot then a library like [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) is probably helpful. [`tput`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tput.html) is also a handy tool, which is also more portable than using raw escape codes. If you are using the raw codes, B/C/D are down/right/left.

It isn't possible with these to have the changing text just "sit there" indefinitely. You can have a particular piece of text sit around indefinitely, with care, by putting the process into the background (with `&` or otherwise). It can move the cursor to the right place, rewrite the text, and then move it back. One example you may find useful, depending on what your end goal is, is [the "clock" demonstration from the Bash prompt howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html). With a *lot* of work and a cooperative terminal emulator you can get enough information back to make that text scroll normally, but it really isn't worthwhile.

Strictly I should note that there is a "blink" code, which does run in what you've called the "backend" and I suppose is technically a change of colour. It behaves like the `<blink>` tag, displaying and hiding the text every so often. It isn't universally supported: Konsole, xterm, the Linux console, and Apple Terminal do implement it, but others generally don't. It's code 5, in any case.

Comment: Some terminals like xterm do allow to change colours dynamically.

Comment: You'll want something like `stty -tstp` if you're going to be backgrounding a terminal writing process.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I'm using gnome-terminal, but still, thanks for the knowledge.